# AWS Lambda cutting my payload in lambda invocation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I fried my brain a long day with a weird problem. I'm trying to send a .docx file document encoded in base64, initially, I thought that the AWS Api Gateway was cutting my body request, but invoking directly via awscli I check the lambda is cutting part of the body payload. Let me show you:

Here a snippet of my lambda function:

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    if event["httpMethod"] == "GET":
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps('Hello from PDFTron! Please send base64 doc to use this Lambda function!')
        }

    elif event["httpMethod"] == "POST":
        try:
            output_path    = "/tmp/"
            body           = json.loads(str(event["body"])) # <--- the error is thrown here
            base64str      = body["file"]["data"]
            filename       = body["file"]["filename"]
            base64_bytes   = base64decode(base64str)
            input_filename = filename.split('.')[0] + "docx"
```

> *Can you check the full file in [lambda_function.py](https://gist.github.com/paulopatto/ae2cecf780de4c8f6c93cf195e9d3147#file-lambda_function-py)*

Ok, now I try call my function via awscli with this command line:

```
aws lambda invoke \
  --profile lab \
  --region us-east-1 \
  --function-name pdf_sign \
  --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out \
  --log-type Tail \
  --query 'LogResult' \
  --output text \
  --payload file://payload.json response.json | base64 -d
```

[payload.json](https://gist.github.com/paulopatto/ae2cecf780de4c8f6c93cf195e9d3147#file-payload-json)

And receive the error:

```
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'}}}
[ERROR] Runtime.MarshalError: Unable to marshal response: Object of type KeyError is not JSON serializable
Traceback (most recent call last):END RequestId: a26b93bd-bcf2-4072-99da-29ffcc3bc350
REPORT RequestId: a26b93bd-bcf2-4072-99da-29ffcc3bc350  Duration: 11.92 ms      Billed Duration: 12 ms  Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 93 MB
```

When I add a debug (print command) on my code I can check that [the payload is cutted](https://gist.github.com/paulopatto/ae2cecf780de4c8f6c93cf195e9d3147#file-print_payload-log) and in the [log error](https://gist.github.com/paulopatto/ae2cecf780de4c8f6c93cf195e9d3147#file-error-log) contains the the final part of my payload (eg. `RX4GAGN1c3RvbVhtbC9pdGVtMS54bWxQSwUGAAAAABEAEQBdBAAAQn8GAAAA'}}}`.

Reading the [aws doc about lambda quotas and limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html), we can see that the invocation payload limit is 6MB,  very different than my payload size (232kb)

| Resource | Quota |
| --- | --- |
| [Invocation payload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-invocation.html) (request and response) | 6 MB each for request and response (synchronous); 256 KB (asynchronous) |

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html

I really think I'm doing all things, into the rules, someone here can tell me and help me, where am i going wrong or misunderstand?

I expect the payload of my request arrives correct in my python function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you logged `event` in your Lambda function?

It seems like the problem is this line:
`body = json.loads(str(event["body"]))`

You are using the CLI and based on [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-awscli.html), the Event will be sent as a String. So you need to JSON parse the event object first.

```
            output_path    = "/tmp/"
            e = json.loads(event)
            body           = str(e["body"])
            base64str      = body["file"]["data"]
            filename       = body["file"]["filename"]
            base64_bytes   = base64decode(base64str)
            input_filename = filename.split('.')[0] + "docx"
```

Comment: Hey @brian, 1st of all,  tks for your help.

Yeah, I tried a similar way (after sleep) and this is the solution. Anyway thank for your, this is a solution.